# How to use Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator with Xamarin?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

How to use Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator with Xamarin.Android?
I have downloaded Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator and Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. I tried to follow tutorials at Microsoft websites but still i have problems with authentication. When I was using real during free trial subscription everything worked.

I know that I have to use SAS keys. But when I create table storage in storage explorer and then generate there SAS it's still wrong. Maybe someone already did that and can paste his code or steps to reproduce connection with storage emulator.

```
const string connectionString = "SharedAccessSignature=sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=91HcGtCMxWM6%2B13mRDH1kej5Wq1a8gRk4WCFd6CeLuk%3D&se=2016-08-01T12%3A16%3A55Z&sp=rwdl;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1";

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Test");
bool exists = await table.ExistsAsync();
if (exists)
    System.Console.WriteLine("Exists");
else
    System.Console.WriteLine("Doesnt exist");
```

**Error Details:**

```
<RequestResult>
  <HTTPStatusCode>0</HTTPStatusCode>
  <HttpStatusMessage />
  <TargetLocation>Primary</TargetLocation>
  <ServiceRequestID />
  <ContentMd5 />
  <Etag />
  <RequestDate />
  <StartTime>Sun, 31 Jul 2016 13:43:44 GMT</StartTime>
  <EndTime>Sun, 31 Jul 2016 13:43:44 GMT</EndTime>
  <Error></Error>
  <ExceptionInfo>
    <Type />
    <HResult>-2146233088</HResult>
    <Message>Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)</Message>
    <Source />
    <StackTrace />
    <InnerExceptionInfo>
      <ExceptionInfo>
        <Type />
        <HResult>-2146233079</HResult>
        <Message>Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)</Message>
        <Source>mscorlib</Source>
        <StackTrace>  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1005 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+&lt;SendAsync&gt;c__async0.MoveNext () [0x003d6] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:372 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+&lt;SendAsyncWorker&gt;c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+&lt;ExecuteAsyncInternal&gt;d__6`1[T].MoveNext () [0x003cf] in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:128 </StackTrace>
        <InnerExceptionInfo>
          <ExceptionInfo>
            <Type />
            <HResult>-2147467259</HResult>
            <Message>Connection refused</Message>
            <Source>System</Source>
            <StackTrace>  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000cb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1313 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:195 </StackTrace>
          </ExceptionInfo>
        </InnerExceptionInfo>
      </ExceptionInfo>
    </InnerExceptionInfo>
  </ExceptionInfo>
</RequestResult>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `But when I create table storage in storage explorer and then generate there SAS it's still wrong`? What's wrong with the SAS?

Comment: When i try to connect to storage using that SAS i get exception about connection failure

Comment: I see. Can you please share your SAS token and also the code to connect  to storage using that SAS token?

Comment: Unfortunately I have already deleted this code, but I will try to recreate it now.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. I believe there's something wrong with the SAS (Duh!!! :)). For starters, a Table SAS should contain a `tn` parameter which is missing in your SAS. Secondly, the permissions for a table in a Table SAS should be `r, a, u, d`. The permissions you have in your SAS is for a blob container (or blob). Are you sure you created a SAS for a table?

Comment: Yes i used Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. Clicked on created by me table and "Get Shared Acces Signature". Maybe there is something wrong with that tool.

Comment: Let me give it a try. I will revert with my finding.

Comment: So I just created a SAS for a table and it seems to create it fine: `?st=2016-07-31T12%3A52%3A00Z&se=2016-08-01T12%3A52%3A00Z&sp=raud&sv=2015-04-05&tn=test&sig=U%2FAuR3Mkx%2FZVr3e4s%2B8ZqaSQMVBhPHuEek1xuCBY6NM%3D`. I am using 0.8.2 version of Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: I was using the wrong string (the second one), because it looked more like SAS.
The first one is:

http://127.0.0.1/devstoreaccount1Testowa?st=2015-07-31T11%3A50%3A00Z&se=2017-08-01T11%3A50%3A00Z&sp=raud&sv=2015-04-05&tn=testowa&sig=UEbinBTgpEGwy1ts0hwmSfELM1lYCBItLHgWpWSgvE4%3D
It has parts you are talking about, but its still not working

Comment: While trying to create a SAS link, I discovered a bug in the storage explorer. Please use this link instead: `http://127.0.0.1/devstoreaccount1/Testowa?st=2015-07-31T11%3A50%3A00Z&se=2017-08-01T11%3A50%3A00Z&sp=raud&sv=2015-04-05&tn=testowa&sig=UEbinBTgpEGwy1ts0hwmSfELM1lYCBItLHgWpWSgvE4%3D`. If you notice, in the link generated by the tool, there is a `/` missing between devstoreaccount1 and your table name. HTH.

Comment: Its still not working. Maybe I am not using it properly?

Comment: Let me try to use your code and see why it is not working.

Comment: Please see my answer below. I just tried that code and it works just fine. HTH.

Comment: Still the same error. Did you use emulator?

Comment: Yes. Can you please ensure that the storage emulator is running?

Comment: When I am running it one more time:
"The storage emulator is already running. Only one instance of the application can be run at the same time."
I'm running it as a admin.

Status "IsRunning: True"

Comment: Hmmm...Can you share the detailed error? I think there's something else going on.

Comment: Thats the output:
http://pastebin.com/UUFNT5uA
I paste in pastebin, because i cant use code formatting i comment

Comment: No issues on using pastebin. I am updating your question with what you are posting there :). Anyways, thank you for sharing the error information. I did some search on that error and based on that I updated my answer. Please see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting this error is because you're running this code in an Emulator. Since the IP address of your emulator is `127.0.0.1`, the requests are not actually hitting the storage emulator but your device emulator only. That's why you're getting this connection refused error. Please see this thread for more details: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1199/how-to-make-our-remote-host-127-0-0-1-reachable-from-android-device-monoandroid-using-vs2010.

What I would recommend is that you use an actual cloud storage account instead of storage emulator to test your code. When you do use the actual storage account, please use the code below (obviously change the connection string appropriately). It should work:

```
        var connectionString = "http://127.0.0.1/devstoreaccount1/Testowa?st=2015-07-31T11%3A50%3A00Z&se=2017-0‌​8-01T11%3A50%3A00Z&sp=raud&sv=2015-04-05&tn=testowa&sig=UEbinBTgpEGwy1ts0hwmSfELM‌​1lYCBItLHgWpWSgvE4%3D";
        CloudTable table = new CloudTable(new Uri(connectionString));
        bool exists = await table.ExistsAsync();
        if (exists)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Exists");
        else
            System.Console.WriteLine("Doesnt exist");
```

Comment: I am running code on my device, not in emulator. But leastwise I know now that is not problem with SAS but connecting to storage emulator. Thank you for your time :) You really helped me

Comment: When you device, do you mean your phone or your computer?

Comment: My phone. Via usb connection

Comment: So essentially it is the same thing. 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of your phone. Can you please try using a real storage account?

Comment: My free trial subscription has already expired. That's why im trying to use emumlator

Comment: Aah....that sucks! If you just want to test the code, you can simply create a console application on your computer and test it that way. In fact, this is what I did above.